# loadFromJSON function from fabric.js does not load image

Tags: image, fabricjs

I'm trying to solve a problem that occurs in a website. Look at this piece of code:

```
var retrievedJSON = workarea["modifiedOptions"];
...
canvasEl = new fabric.Canvas("canvas_" + view[i]["id"]);
                    if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(retrievedJSON))
                    {
                        for (var work in retrievedJSON)
                        {
                            canvasEl.loadFromJSON(retrievedJSON[work], function() {
                                canvasEl.renderAll();
                                canvasEl.on("object:added", mouseDown);
                            });
                        }
                    }
```

There is a line where I suppose It's trying to load a json and put Its elements in the canvas:
canvasEl.loadFromJSON(retrievedJSON[work]

The json which is being loaded is that one:

```
"{"objects":[{"type":"text","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":14.08,"top":16,"width":160.84,"height":31.2,"fill":"rgb(61, 183, 228)","stroke":"rgb(0, 0, 0)","strokeWidth":0.1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","text":"rascunho4","fontSize":"24","fontWeight":"normal","fontFamily":"MetalMacabre","fontStyle":"","lineHeight":1.3,"textDecoration":"","textAlign":"center","path":null,"textBackgroundColor":"","useNative":true},{"type":"image","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":14.08,"top":17,"width":200,"height":200,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":0.76,"scaleY":0.76,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","src":"http://mydomain.com.br/tool/media/image/1454337092.png","filters":[{"type":"Resize"}],"crossOrigin":"","alignX":"none","alignY":"none","meetOrSlice":"meet"}],"background":""}"
```

As you can see there is a text and an image, but just the text is being loaded to the canvas. The image does not appear in the canvas on the screen. Why does that happens? Any idea? Do you think could be something wrong with my json?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your JSON is incorrect. Please remove the leading and trailing double quotes in your JSON. Then JSON will be okay,

Could you please try this code with my JSON as below.

var json = '{"objects":[{"type":"path","left":104,"top":96,"width":99,"height":115,"fill":"#00274D","overlayFill":null,"stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"scaleX":1.04,"scaleY":1.04,"angle":-25.8,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"selectable":true,"path":[["M",67.39,22.39],["c",2.59,-0.43,5.11,1.44,5.54,4.18],["c",0.43,2.66,-1.3,5.26,-3.89,5.69],["c",-1.8,0.29,-3.6,-0.58,-4.61,-2.02],["L",44.5,34.56],["l",10.87,59.62],["c",17.42,-4.46,26.06,-14.18,27.5,-29.02],["l",-10.01,-0.72],["L",88.7,51.91],["l",9.43,21.24],["c",-3.38,-1.95,-5.9,-5.11,-9.29,-7.06],["c",-0.29,25.06,-27.14,32.76,-33.77,47.95],["C",44.42,100.08,26.5,114.77,6.91,82.8],["L",0,92.45],["l",1.51,-21.6],["l",19.66,4.68],["l",-9.43,3.67],["c",7.49,11.59,17.57,19.87,36.43,16.42],["L",36.22,36.57],["l",-18.65,2.38],["c",-0.14,2.16,-1.73,4.03,-3.89,4.39],["c",-2.59,0.43,-5.04,-1.44,-5.54,-4.1],["c",-0.43,-2.74,1.3,-5.26,3.89,-5.69],["c",1.94,-0.36,3.89,0.65,4.9,2.3],["l",17.93,-4.82],["l",-1.37,-6.84],["c",-4.82,-0.79,-8.93,-4.75,-9.79,-10.08],["c",-1.15,-6.62,3.1,-12.89,9.43,-13.97],["c",6.41,-1.01,12.46,3.46,13.54,10.08],["c",0.86,5.18,-1.58,10.15,-5.69,12.6],["l",1.87,6.12],["l",20.74,-2.88],["C",64.01,24.26,65.52,22.75,67.39,22.39],["L",67.39,22.39],["z"],["M",33.91,5.18],["c",-3.46,0.58,-5.76,3.96,-5.11,7.56],["c",0.58,3.6,3.89,6.05,7.27,5.47],["c",3.46,-0.58,5.76,-3.96,5.18,-7.56],["C",40.61,7.05,37.37,4.61,33.91,5.18],["z"]]}],"background":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"}';

canvas.loadFromDatalessJSON(json);